# Choosing which Enum to use dynamically in Java

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I need to dynamically choose an Enum with some properties based on a parameter that will provide the suffix of the Enum name to use.
I tried this but the "**getCodigoAsString()**" method doesn't work.

**An Enum sample:**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@AllArgsConstructor @Getter
public enum Chaves_35 {
    MODELO_DISPOSITIVO(1234,"TEXT","IN","Modelo Dispositivo"),
    DISPOSITIVO_SUPORTA_MULTI_TAREFA(4423,"TEXT","IN","Dispositivo Suporta Multi Tarefa"),
    NOME_DISPOSITIVO(7845,"TEXT","IN","Nome Dispositivo"),
    IDIOMA_DISPOSITIVO(3288,"TEXT","IN","Idioma Dispositivo"),
    ;

    private int codigo;
    private String tipo;
    private String fluxo;
    private String descricao;
  
    public String getCodigoAsString() {
        return String.valueOf(codigo);
    }
    
}
```

**The Class that make the choice:**

```
 public class ChavesCanal { 

    public static Enum<?>[] BuscaChavesCanal(int idCanal) {
        Enum<?>[] resp = null;

        switch (idCanal) {
            case 6:
                resp = Chaves_6.values();
                break;
            case 8:
                resp = Chaves_8.values();
                break;
            case 10:
                resp = Chaves_10.values();
                break;
            case 17:
                resp = Chaves_17.values();
                break;
            case 21:
                resp = Chaves_21.values();
                break;
            case 22:
                resp = Chaves_22.values();
                break;
            case 27:
                resp = Chaves_27.values();
                break;
            case 28:
                resp = Chaves_28.values();
                break;
            case 35:
                resp = Chaves_35.values();
                break;
            case 37:
                resp = Chaves_37.values();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return resp;
    }
}
```

**This is the method that I'm trying to use the "ChavesCanal()" Class:**

```
public static boolean VerificaChavesCanais_JSON(int codigoCanal) {
        if(codigoCanal <= 0) return false;

        JSONObject payloadJSON = new JSONObject("{\"1\":\"35\",\"8\":\"2021-06-29 14:33:41.121\",\"35\":\"Windows 10\",\"1234\":\"Computer\",\"3288\":\"PT-BR\",\"4423\":\"SIM\",\"7732\":\"64x\",\"7845\":\"PC_MAPS_01\"}");
        
        try {
            for (Enum<?> chaveId : ChavesCanal.BuscaChavesCanal(codigoCanal)) {
                if(!payloadJSON.has(chaveId.getCodigoAsString())) {
                    System.out.println("  .... chave '" + chaveId.getCodigoAsString() + "' não encontrada!!!");
                }
            }

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERRO em VerificaChavesCanais_JSON(): " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks folks!!!

Comment: What is not working? What is the `payloadJSON` content?

Comment: Hi @EmersonPardo.
The "chaveId.getCodigoAsString()" is not working (in the last block of code).
Occour the error: _The method getCodigoAsString() is undefined for the type Enum<capture#2-of ?>_.
This method is inside the Enum **Chaves_35**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is working that way. When you define `Enum<?>` the compiler cannot know that the `enum` you want provides the method `getCodigoAsString` so you'd get that compile error.

At least from the code you showed it seems that an enum is not the right data structure for your needs. To you use the enum values at all? You should consider to put that type of information in a more suitable data structure like a `Map` for example. So you get rid of the entire `switch` stuff.

Side note: `ChavesCanal.BuscaChavesCanal` violates java naming convention. Should be named `ChavesCanal.buscaChavesCanal`.